# How do I make InStr case sensitve in MS Access

Tags: string, ms-access, vba, string-comparison

How do I make InStr case sensitive in MS Access?

I'd like the following to display `0`

```
 msgbox InStr("In Here", "here")
```

Instead I get `4`.

I've tried adding vbBinaryCompare

```
 msgbox InStr("In Here", "here", vbBinaryCompare)
```

but it complains about a type mismatch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The help topic doesn't make this point clear, but when you use the optional *compare* argument, you need to also supply the optional *start* argument in order to avoid that type mismatch complaint.

So this displays 0 in the `MsgBox`:

```
MsgBox InStr(1,"In Here", "here", vbBinaryCompare)
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `InStrB` instead of `InStr`. Then it will do a byte by byte comparison instead of case insensitive.

```
 msgbox InStrB("In Here", "here")
```

Displays `0`.